# Boot and run from USB

Tags: boot, usb

Is it possible for me to run and use Ubuntu or other Linux from USB and it will remember what I did??? Like if I installed it on a computer?? Eg. if I write a dockument, will it remember it and how do I do it?
I have tried all the programs I have found on the net, but nothing helped, is it even possible? Hope for answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you install a Live-Disk to a USB-Drive with the [startup disk creator](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu) you can create a space on the drive to store the information which was created during Ubuntu was running from USB Drive.

Take a look at the linked page. In picture 6 you can see the option, called "Stored in reserved extra space".

Comment: I managed to install Linux on the USB, i just pulled out the HDD and run the CD. Went fine so far. :)

Comment: Glad to hear that ... so far :)

Comment: yeah, works fine, and i got 16GB so i got a lot of space to store on. :) and i can download and install programs and other stuff to it. :)

Comment: but, now i need help. how do i in a easy way download and install flash player and Unity3d??? :)

Comment: You should open a new question for that. Nobody will see the here.